# USB DVD device type, /dev designation

Tags: centos, mount, dvd

What is the device type of an external USB DVD player to use when using the Linux mount command?  ISO9660 is the type for the internal CDROM.  What is the corresponding type for a DVD drive?  Are there different types is the DVD is read only or read-write?

Within /dev, SR0 appears to be the internal CD drive.  What is the /dev designation of the external USB DVD drive?

Comment: You confuse device types and file systems. ISO9660 is a file system. DVDs usually use the file system UDF.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of USB drive (hardware) you mount. If you're uncomfortable looking through the `dmesg` log you can use the tool `hwinfo` to find this out.

```
$ sudo hwinfo --cdrom|grep "Device File"
  Device File: /dev/sr0 (/dev/sg1)
  Device Files: /dev/sr0, /dev/block/11:0, /dev/scd0, /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-1:0:0:0, /dev/cdrom, /dev/cdrw, /dev/dvd, /dev/dvdrw
```

The "Device File" is  the device you're looking for. If you want to see all the manufacturer info about the CD/DVD drive you can run that same command without the `grep`.

```
$ sudo hwinfo --cdrom
```

However, I usually do not include any `-type` when mounting most CD/DVDs. If you have to provide a type it's typically `-t iso9660` for CDROMs and `-t udf` for DVDs.

#### References

- [CD/DVD drive not mounted when inserted with Disc of any kind](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76860/cd-dvd-drive-not-mounted-when-inserted-with-disc-of-any-kind)
- [Mount an ISO Image in Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/wiki/Mount_an_ISO_Image_in_Linux)